# MYSQL Query with ORDER BY runs very slow in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

When I use paginate function in Cakephp 2.0 with $options['order'] = array('Model.name' => 'DESC'); set query takes 7000ms compared to 5ms without order set up, limit is set to only 10 records. I use WAMP server.

Any idea why does this query take so long? The only difference is adding order rule. "Ordered by" field is indexed.

**Solved it:**

The problem was that I didn't set all related models id fields (model_id) as indexes, after doing that the query runs as it should.

Comment: If you run the full SQL query in the mysql CLI, but prepended with `EXPLAIN`, what is output?

Comment: Post some of your code of your query and the database table

Comment: What a mess...in case you are SELECTing all fields from a table, you may use `myTable.*` instead of listing all fields.

Comment: It's the output from  echo $this->element('sql_dump');

Comment: +1 for finding and putting the solution after your question. :)

Comment: If your problem is solved, then post the solution as an answer, and accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting `order` in your Model.

```
var $order = "field";
var $order = "Model.field";
var $order = "Model.field asc";
var $order = "Model.field ASC";
var $order = "Model.field DESC";
var $order = array("Model.field" => "asc", "Model.field2" => "DESC");
```

`Delete-orderBy` in your query and put one of these options in your Model and tell us is it faster.

[Source](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1064/order)

Comment: It doesn't change anything. SQL Query is exactly the same :(

Comment: Is it any faster when you execute this query outside of CakePHP? Let's say PHPMYADMIN?